# My javascript server code can read a "2011", why not a "20,11" if they are both String?

Tags: javascript, express, redis, socket.io, apache-storm

I'm connecting Storm to javascript via redis. The redis part works fine, but when I try to publish tuples(really Strings), my code (an example from internet just a little modified) doesn't recieve a thing, and redis recieves well the tuples. Here's my code:

```
/*
    Node.js server script
    Required node packages: express, redis, socket.io
*/
const PORT = 3000;
const HOST = 'localhost';

var express = require('express'),
    http = require('http'), 
    server = http.createServer(app);
    log('info', 'connected to express');
var app = express();

const redis = require('redis');
const client = redis.createClient();
log('info', 'connected to redis server');

const io = require('socket.io');

if (!module.parent) {
    server.listen(PORT, HOST);
    const socket  = io.listen(server);

    socket.on('connection', function(client) {
        const subscribe = redis.createClient()
        subscribe.subscribe('realtime');

        subscribe.on("message", function(channel, message) {
            client.send(message);
            log('msg', "received from channel #" + channel + " : " + message);
        });

        client.on('message', function(msg) {
            log('debug', msg);
        });

        client.on('disconnect', function() {
            log('warn', 'disconnecting from redis');
            subscribe.quit();
        });
    });
}

function log(type, msg) {

    var color   = '\u001b[0m',
        reset = '\u001b[0m';

    switch(type) {
        case "info":
            color = '\u001b[36m';
            break;
        case "warn":
            color = '\u001b[33m';
            break;
        case "error":
            color = '\u001b[31m';
            break;
        case "msg":
            color = '\u001b[34m';
            break;
        default:
            color = '\u001b[0m'
    }

    console.log(color + '   ' + type + '  - ' + reset + msg);
}
```

It send to terminal the message when i send ints, but not with tuples.I am just quite a noob with JavaScript, and I don't see why it can't read a tuple just like an int.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well I do not think JavaScript has tuples so what is being returned from the call exactly?

Comment: Are you sure these unicode character tuples makes sense while outputting. 
[more info ](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-unicode)

Comment: to epascarello,I think I'm going to edit this, I think it's a String, cause the message from redis publish method is something like this: "PUBLISH" "realtime" "3,5,6,8,5,1,2,3,6,211". So what do you think it shoul'd be?
To Sukhmeet Singh, I'm reading the info you passed me, I'll comment something soon.

Thank you both!

Comment: I just edited the question, i think it's more accurate now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I sent the messages, in the treatmen at redis, they where splitted, now they aren't, and the messages arrives to the client.

Thanks for your answers!